# Source location for installed packages - Groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In groovy (maybe only catkin packages) the source code for installed packages do not appear in the package directories (i.e. the directory found using roscd).  I know the source code can be found in the original repository, but this may not be exactly what is installed.  Is there a tarball somewhere that captures the source code for a particular installed version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64379/source-location-for-installed-packages---groovy/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that you can find the source code as part of the *-release repositories.

For instance, if you wanted the source code for the 1.9.30 release of Rviz in Hydro for Quantal, you can go to Github:

https://github.com/ros-gbp/rviz-release/tree/debian/ros-hydro-rviz_1.9.30-0_quantal

Bloom automates the creation of the specific branches and tags for the released versions.  This is the source that the buildfarm then uses to generate the debs.

The release repositories will be listed in the [`rosdistro` repository](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/release.yaml)

Edit: Forgot to mention that Github allows for downloading tarballs of git tags, such as:

`https://github.com/ros-gbp/rviz-release/archive/debian/ros-hydro-rviz_1.9.30-0_quantal.tar.gz`

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1